# invertir un número ingresado ¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber cual es el error o si estoy planteando mal el problema.

```js
var cantidad = 123;
while (cantidad > 0) {
  var digito = cantidad % 10;
  var cantidadInvertida = (cantidadInvertida * 10) + digito;
  cantidad = Math.floor(cantidad / 10);
}
```

Comment: =P has probado rotar la pantalla? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005383/1423096

Answer (score 2):

Saludos

En caso no sea obligatorio realizar las operaciones de división:

```
var cantidad = 123; // Cualquier número que quieras
var arreglo = (""+cantidad + "").split(''); // Lo "convertimos a cadena" y en arreglo
arreglo.reverse(); // Invierte el arreglo.
```

y simplemente ve sacando desde el elemento 0 al *n* y usas la instrucción que corresponda para colocarlo en la **salida de tu resultado**.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Roberto León Oramas por su gran ayuda con este ejercicio.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te ocurre es que le estas multiplicando cantidadInvertida * 10 mientras que cantidadInvertida tiene un valor nulo, debes declararla antes para hacer eso.

```
var cantidad = 123;
var cantidadInvertida = 0;
while (cantidad > 0) {
  var digito = cantidad % 10;
  cantidadInvertida = (cantidadInvertida * 10) + digito;
  cantidad = Math.floor(cantidad / 10);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la gran ayuda con este ejercicio.